# How can I remove an address from an array in solidity foundry testing?

Tags: testing, solidity

I came across trying to remove an address from an array of funders in case the funding reverts due to an error.

```
function test_Fund() public {
        fundMe.fund{value: 6 * 10 ** 18}();
        assertEq(
            fundMe.addressToAmountFunded(msg.sender),
            6 * 10 ** 18,
            "Incorrect amount funded"
        );
        assertEq(
            fundMe.funders(fundMe.funders.fundersIndex - 1),
            msg.sender,
            "Incorrect funder address"
        );
    }
```

The error I am getting comes from:

```
(fundMe.funders.fundersIndex - 1)
```

So is there any other way to solve this?